# python: combination of lists in dict, with various size of list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, combinations

Five params can have various len (including empty). I wrote long code for first three params, for more params it icrement for bigger code with repeats. How minimize code?

```
params1 = [1,2]
params2 = []
params3 = [3,4,5,6]
# ...
params5 = [7,8]

# for 3 params example:
summary = {}
if 0 < len(params1):
    for param1 in params1:
        summary['param1'] = param1
        if 0 < len(params2):
            for param2 in params2:
                summary['param2'] = param2
                if 0 < len(params3):
                    for param3 in params3:
                        summary['param3'] = param3
                        print summary
                else:
                    print summary
        else:
            if 0 < len(params3):
                for param3 in params3:
                    summary['param3'] = param3
                    print summary
            else:
                print summary
else:
    if 0 < len(params2):
        for param2 in params2:
            summary['param2'] = param2
            if 0 < len(param3):
                for param3 in params3:
                    summary['param3'] = param3
                    print summary
            else:
                print summary
    else:
        if 0 < len(params3):
            for param3 in params3:
                summary['param3'] = param3
                print summary
        else:
            print summary
```

Need get dict with combinations non empty params, output of example code:

```
{'param3': 3, 'param1': 1}
{'param3': 4, 'param1': 1}
{'param3': 5, 'param1': 1}
{'param3': 6, 'param1': 1}
{'param3': 3, 'param1': 2}
{'param3': 4, 'param1': 2}
{'param3': 5, 'param1': 2}
{'param3': 6, 'param1': 2}
```

How to replace example code to smallest lines?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, what are params?

Comment: Do you want all the [combinations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) of those parameters?

Comment: Have you ever played [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What happened to `param5`?  Why don't its values appear in the output?

Comment: I'm trying to send JSON format to server

Comment: I want all of the combinations, except empty

Comment: param5 and param4 was ommited for smallest listing of examle code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using recursion :

```
def affich(params, summary = None):
#print(params, summary )
if len(params) == 0:
    print summary
else:
    if summary is None: summary = {}
    name, pars = params[0]
    if len(pars) == 0:
        affich(params[1:], summary )
    else:
        for p in pars:
            cur[name] = p
            affich(params[1:], summary )

affich((('params1', [1, 2]), ('params2', []), ('params3', [3, 4, 5, 6]), ('params5', [7, 8]))
```

gives :

```
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 3}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 3}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 4}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 4}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 5}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 5}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 6}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 1, 'params3': 6}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 3}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 3}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 4}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 4}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 5}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 5}
{'params5': 7, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 6}
{'params5': 8, 'params1': 2, 'params3': 6}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is shortest solution

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import itertools    
>>> params1 = [1,2]
>>> params2 = [None]
>>> params3 = [3,4,5,6]
>>> # ...
>>> params5 = [7,8]
>>> print [x for x in itertools.product(params1, params2, ... , params5)]
[(1, None, 3), (1, None, 4), (1, None, 5), (1, None, 6), (2, None, 3), (2, None, 4), (2, None, 5), (2, None, 6)]
```

Comment: yes, this is I will use if no other code can't find